# Subtract two categorical columns from each other in a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame which has two categorical column. I want to subtract one from the other and have it as a new column:
Here is an example:

```
    > df<-data.frame(Id=1:3,name=c("Cer[AP] t44:0; [M-H]-","FA 20:0; [M-Na]-","PG 36:1; PG(18:0/18:1)[M-H]+"),
charge=c("[M-H]-","[M-Na]-","[M-H]+"))
    > df
      Id                         name  charge
    1  1        Cer[AP] t44:0; [M-H]-  [M-H]-
    2  2             FA 20:0; [M-Na]- [M-Na]-
    3  3 PG 36:1; PG(18:0/18:1)[M-H]+  [M-H]+
```

I want to match column `charge` with `name` and remove it from `name` column to have this output:

```
 Id                         name    charge               new_name
1  1        Cer[AP] t44:0; [M-H]-   [M-H]-          Cer[AP] t44:0;
2  2             FA 20:0;  [M-Na]-  [M-Na]-         FA 20:0;
3  3 PG 36:1; PG(18:0/18:1)[M-H]+   [M-H]+          PG 36:1; PG(18:0/18:1)
```

Thank you for your help,
I tried many matching and removing functions but didn't get the result I want it.

Comment: The output you posted does not match the problem description. For instance, in row 1, shouldn't `new_name` become just `Cer[AP] t44:0;`? Why is `FA 20:0;` **not** in row 2?There's a similar inconsistency in row 3.

Comment: you are right, I just corrected it. basically I want to match the third column with second one then remove that match from second one, and save it as a new column.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will do it. The first `sub` is needed to escape the meta-characters `[` and `]` that are present in column `"charge"`.

```
sapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(i){
  x <- df[i, "name"]
  y <- df[i, "charge"]
  trimws(sub(y, "", x, fixed = TRUE))
})
#[1] "Cer[AP] t44:0;"          "FA 20:0;"               
#[3] "PG 36:1; PG(18:0/18:1)"
```

So all you have to do is to assign the output of the above to the new column.

```
df$new_name <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(i){
  x <- df[i, "name"]
  y <- df[i, "charge"]
  trimws(sub(y, "", x, fixed = TRUE))
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still have that "+" in the third row.

Comment: Set the `fixed=TRUE` argument of `sub`, without the need of escaping anything. For instance: `mapply(sub,as.character(df$charge),as.character(df$name),MoreArgs=list(replacement="",fixed=TRUE))`, or still better with the `stringr` package which provides full vectorization: `str_replace(as.character(df$name),fixed(as.character(df$charge)),"")`.

Comment: @nicola I believe you should post your comment as an answer. In particular, `str_replace` is much better than my `sapply`. (Also `mapply`, btw.)